# Install packages from source failing - Dockerfile

Tags: r, docker, package

I am trying to install some packages from source (including package that I have created that installed fine with R console or even when R CMD install.

However, while building docker-image using a docker file. I get this error with for this line in the docker file

```
RUN R -e 'install.packages("RcppDIUtilsPackage_1.0.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")'
```

I also tried many other commands including `R CMD INSTALL` all work fine to install the package except within the docker image build.

Here is the error i am encountering.

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: invalid package ‘RcppDIUtilsPackage_1.0.tar.gz’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning message:
In install.packages("RcppDIUtilsPackage_1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL,  :
  installation of package ‘RcppDIUtilsPackage_1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Thanks!!

Edit: The Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.4.4

WORKDIR /home/ubuntu/projects/DService

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  libssl-dev \
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev

RUN R -e "install.packages('plumber')"

RUN R -e "install.packages('Rcpp')"

RUN R -e 'install.packages("RcppDIUtilsPackage_1.0.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")'

COPY / /

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["Rscript", "DService.R"]

command: sudo docker build --no-cache -t dservice-docker-image .
```

Comment: On the surface, it looks like your docker volume mount is missing, not correct, or your current working directory is not what you think it is. You might either explicitly set [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) to where the `.tar.gz` file is copied, change where you [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) the file, or something similar. It might help to see your `Dockerfile` and the `docker` command you're using the instantiate the container.

Comment: Hi r2evans, Thanks for your response. I have originally set the WORKDIR as shown in Dockerfile (see the edited version of the post) with the correct location of all the files including the .tar.gz file.

Comment: For some reason, I'm experiencing the same problem after rebuilding a Docker container that includes installations from source. I had no issues before. I will post if I find a solution.

Comment: I'm a little nervous with `COPY / /`, this seems a bit expansive. Having said that, are you certain that it is actually copying your `.tar.gz` into the directory? If you include `if (file.exists("RcppDIUtilsPackage_1.0.tar.gz")) install.packages(...)`, does it still error?

Comment: I actually use WORKDIR /app  and then use ADD . /App and seems to work but gives me another dependency error now: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘Rcpp’ 0.12.17 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘RcppDIUtilsPackage’

although RCPP is installed before that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect solution to your problem, because I was not able to resolve the same issue.

The root of the issue may have something to do with the host environment that created the Docker image from the Dockerfile. Specifically, the R instance that is spun up to install the local packages may not being able to access the path to where your local packages are stored.

The solution for me was to just avoid local packages. Move any local repositories to remote repositories, and reference them in the Dockerfile instead. e.g.

```
RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('dmanuge/shinyFilesWidget') ; system('echo 14')"
```

After that, rebuilt your Docker image and run it accordingly. While this is not a direct solution, I reached the critical threshold of debugging and needed to move on. :)